# Choosing multiple Hibernate import.sql based on conditions

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, import, runtime

How can I specify which import file I want hibernate to run. Is there any configuration option that I can put (I think I have seen something like this somewhere) that I can say custom .sql file and hibernate will run it.

I want to split my creation into multiple files. And also I want to run differnet scripts that will generate date based on my hibernate config that I am using. So if I am using local it should one set of .sql files and if I am testing it into QA it should use another.

I have multiple config files that I can run depending on what I want, so now I need to figure out how to put which script should run in which configuration.

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files' is the setting you want (org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings#HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES).

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES